# Question about the notation of vectors in respect to their domains

Tags: notation, vectors

A column vector $a$ is said to an element of R^(4) when $a$ is

[1, 2, 3, 4]' (*Transpose of this row vector*).

Therefore my question lies in the fact that I do not understand how row vectors can be represented with this notation. I also understand that Matrices can be represented by for e.g. R^(3 x 4).

Comment: I don't understand your first claim. For $a$ to be an element of $\Bbb R^4$, $a$ just needs to be a 4-tuple with real entries, i.e., $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ where $a_i\in\Bbb R~\forall~1\leq i\leq 4$. You don't need to take the transpose of it. It is actually a notational thing. You can either use row or column vectors as you like. It doesn't really matter. Just stick to a particular notation and don't mix stuff up.

Comment: @learner For a to be an element of R^4, it can be both a row and a column vector, but has to be a 4-tuple? I did not know this. How can you differenciate between the two with this notation?

Comment: A *column* vector is a *matrix* $(4 \times 1)$ while a *row* vector is a *matrix* $(1 \times 4)$. We (humans) write them "spatially", but if you write a *software* you cannot "enter" the inputs "by columns"; what you have to declare to the computer is the *data structure* : in this case you have to declare in advance that the $4$ numbers must be read as a $(4 \times 1)$ matrix or as a $(1 \times 4)$ one.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Perfectly understand now. Should I delete the question?

Comment: As you want ... Otherwise, if you find the answer below useful, you can accept/upvote it, in order to "reward" the guy has written it for his effort. :-)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry, I didn't know anyone wanted write an answer. I thought this was question was a bit silly after these comments, but thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements of $\Bbb R^n$ are actually just (finite) sequences of real numbers.  For instance $x=\{x_k\}_{k=1}^4$ where $x_k = 2k-3$ is an element of $\Bbb R^4$.  Often there's no succinct way to write the vector as a nice formula like this, though, and in fact it's more convenient to just write out each element if $n$ is small enough.

That leaves us with the question of how we should write out the sequence.  We could for instance write it out in tuple notation as $$x=(-1,1,3,5)$$
or row matrix notation as $$x = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 & 3 & 5\end{bmatrix}$$ or column matrix notation as $$x = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 3 \\ 5\end{bmatrix}$$

Which of these is the "correct" way of writing the vector $x\in \Bbb R^4$?  Any of them.  As long as we restrict ourselves to componentwise addition and scalar multiplication there is no difference between any of the above three ways of writing $x$ -- they are just different notations.

However the benefit of writing our vector as a row or column matrix is that if we also allow matrix multiplication to be performed on it, then *any* linear transformation can be represented by the multiplication (left or right multiplication depending on whether we're using column or row matrices to represent our vector) of a our vector by a *unique* matrix.

So, from one point of view, writing our vector in $\Bbb R^4$ as a matrix introduces extra structure on the vector by allowing a type of multiplication not defined on $\Bbb R^4$.  BUT that multiplication can always be interpreted as the application of a linear transformation on the vector.  So practically speaking, there really is no difference in writing a vector in *any* of the above three ways.

Sometimes it is convenient however to specify which of the above types of representations we're using for our vector.  In that case I like to call the space of row matrices $M_{1\times n}(\Bbb R)$ and the space of column matrices $M_{n\times 1}(\Bbb R)$ (and of course the space of $n\times m$ matrices is denoted $M_{n\times m}(\Bbb R)$) where the $\Bbb R$ tells us that each of the entries are real numbers.

I don't know of a standard way to denote the space of $n$-tuples.  Some would say that as tuples don't introduce any extra structure to $\Bbb R^n$ that they are in fact the "correct" representation.  Meaning that the space of $n$-tuples really is just $\Bbb R^n$.  I have nothing against that viewpoint, but remember that elements of $\Bbb R^n$ are just sequences of real numbers.  You can write out those numbers any way you like -- with round parentheses, square parentheses, commas, as a column, as a row, etc -- but fundamentally it's the *operations* that you allow on those numbers which really define $\Bbb R^n$.  So write your vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ any way you like, but stick to whichever convention you choose in a given problem so that you don't confuse your reader.